# Error C2679 while trying to serialize QList of custom class with QDatastream

Tags: c++, qt, serialization

I got a custom class `Foo`:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    // getters and setters
    // ...
private:
    QString string;
    QStringList list;
    int number;
}
```

The serialization of `Foo` has worked as expected:

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const Foo &foo)
{
    stream<<foo.getString()<<foo.getList()<<foo.getNumber();
    return stream;
}
```

but when I attempted to serialize `QList<Foo>`, I got

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type “const Foo”
```

which directed to the corresponding Qt code (qdatastream.h):

```
template <typename T>
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& s, const QList<T>& l)
{
    s << quint32(l.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i)
        s << l.at(i); // <--- compiler error here
    return s;
}
```

I know `QList<T>::at()` returns `const T &`, but I have no idea why it should fail to compile here. Please point out my error, I'd like to know how to fix this. Also, if I miss the necessary parts of code please do let me know. Thanks!

[**Edit**]:
For reference, my environment is Qt 4.8.5 with MSVC2010/ Win 7 and I am using Qt creator.

Besides, this is how I serialize `QList<Foo>`:

```
QFile file("file.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QDataStream out(&file);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);

out<<fooList; // It's the instant of QList<Foo> and it's not a pointer
//^^^^^^^^^^ compiler errors occurs as this line is added
```

[**Last Edit**]:

I finally figure out what's going on:

The operator overload that I defined to serialize `Foo` is written in a **seperate** `.cpp` file, where

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const Foo &foo)
{
    stream<<foo.getString()<<foo.getList()<<foo.getNumber();
    return stream;
}
```

is inside `foo.cpp`.

The above code **can be compiled** but now I realize that **it will never be used!**

The serialization of `QList<Foo>` is implemented in another file `notFoo.cpp`, which is a *"bigger class"*.

As I compile `notFoo.cpp`, only the definition and methods inside the header `qdatastream.h` could be found hence the **error C2679** comes out, where:

```
template <typename T>
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& s, const QList<T>& l)
{
    s << quint32(l.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i)
        s << l.at(i); // <--- compiler error here
    return s;
}
```

It shows that compiler doesn't know how to further serialze type `Foo`.

```
binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type “const Foo”
```

which means `<<` of `s << l.at(i);` is not found (since I defined it in another `.cpp` file)

After I move the serialization method from `Foo.cpp` to `notFoo.cpp`, the code can finally be compiled.

[**Conclusion**]:

The compiler didn't find the function signature in the `Foo.h` since I define the stream operator inline within `Foo.cpp`.

Comment: Hm, strange, but this code works for me (Win7, Qt 4.8.5, MSVC9).

Comment: It's weird. I've added more information to OP.

Comment: What is `fooList` and how do you create and populate it?

Comment: `QList<Foo> fooList;` after that, `fooList.append(Foo);` My app appends `Foo` to `QList` at runtime.

Comment: @vahancho I am not sure if this info. helps: I save `fooList` in an object. But I constantly get this error either I call a getter to return `fooList` to output datastream or I move `fooList` to `public` and directly call it through the instant.

Comment: I think, if you show the complete code that triggers this error, it would help to understand the problem.

Comment: @vahancho Thank you for your response. It's a medium size project and I am not sure which part I should emphasize but I will try making it as detailed as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **declare** the stream operator in the same header where you declare the serialized type:

```
// Foo.h
#include <QString>
#include <QDataStream>

class Foo
{
public:
    // getters and setters
    // ...
private:
    QString string;
    QStringList list;
    int number;
};

QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const Foo &foo);
```

Usually, the operator's **implementation** will be in the file where you implement `Foo`, but it could be in any .cpp file, really:

```
// Foo.cpp

Foo::Foo() {
  ...
}

...

QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const Foo &foo)
{
    stream<<foo.getString()<<foo.getList()<<foo.getNumber();
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I shouldn't do that inline.